# Programmatically change class to custom class

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

using the package `openxlsx` to prepare the writing of a dataframe to an excel workbook, I am able to run the example in the [openxlsx's vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/vignettes/formatting.pdf) using the column per column way to change the variable's `class`.

```
## data.frame to write
df <- data.frame("Date" = Sys.Date()-0:4,
"Logical" = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
"Currency" = paste("$",-2:2),
"Accounting" = -2:2,
"hLink" = "http://cran.r-project.org/",
"Percentage" = seq(-1, 1, length.out=5),
"TinyNumber" = runif(5) / 1E9, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Below comes the custom class assignation used for excel formatting
class(df$Currency)   <- "currency"
class(df$Accounting) <- "accounting"
class(df$hLink)      <- "hyperlink"
class(df$Percentage) <- "percentage"
class(df$TinyNumber) <- "scientific"

## Works !
class(df$Percentage)
[1] "percentage"
```

In order to work with my own dataset I would like to use `dplyr` to change the class of columns whose name is matching a given string (as below).

What I've tried so far:

```
require(tidyverse)
fn_toPercentage <- function(x){class(x)<-"percentage"}

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Percent")),funs(fn_toPercentage))

## Check:
lapply(df2,class)
$Date
[1] "Date"

$Logical
[1] "logical"

$Currency
[1] "character"

$Accounting
[1] "integer"

$hLink
[1] "character"

## Failed !    
$Percentage
[1] "character"

$TinyNumber
[1] "numeric"
```

I have the feeling that the function `setAs` might be relevant for my problem, but I cannot figure out how to use it.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an error in `fn_toPercentage`. It should looks like this:

```
fn_toPercentage <- function(x){
    class(x)<-"percentage"
    x
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gregory !